# Jboss server hangs when it try to obtain a connection from HypersonicDB data source

Tags: jboss, hsqldb

I know cleaning cache will work because tables are cached. But a certain line in my script causing problems here is the content. Please help me understand the line highlighted in bold.

// create table

CREATE CACHED TABLE JMS_MESSAGES(MESSAGEID INTEGER NOT NULL,DESTINATION VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,TXID INTEGER,TXOP CHAR(1),MESSAGEBLOB OBJECT,PRIMARY KEY(MESSAGEID,DESTINATION))

// create indexes

CREATE INDEX JMS_MESSAGES_TXOP_TXID ON JMS_MESSAGES(TXOP,TXID)

CREATE INDEX JMS_MESSAGES_DESTINATION ON JMS_MESSAGES(DESTINATION)

// what is it doing? because this line makes it hang

**SET TABLE JMS_MESSAGES INDEX'3883576 3883576 3883576 0'**

Please let me know what this line does so I can debug this script. On production we are using Jboss 4.0.4 and don't often clear tmp/work often and reboot system every Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the line reported in bold and save the .script file with no other change.

The purpose of the line is to link to the data in the .data file. As this is a message cache that is no longer valid, there should be no data there.